# Storing NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsvalue

I am currently storing an instance of a class in an `NSMutableArray` by using `NSValue` with "valueWithPointer". The problem is within this class I have another `NSMutableArray`, whenever I convert the instance of the class back from `NSValue` the `NSMutableArray` contained within it is of length 0, all of its elements have been removed. Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Need to see code to give any kind of advice.

Comment: Why do u use NSValue to store an object? just user addObject:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's a *very good* reason that you specifically need NSValue, you should *not* add a class instance to an NSMutableArray that way. Just do:

```
[myMutableArray addObject:myClassInstance];
```

This does all the right things with regards to memory management (and avoids ugly pointer value stuff), and should let you get at your class instance's array objects after retrieving the object. See [the NSMutableArray docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for a quick starter on how to use the class properly.